# Entity framework with AutoMapper to handle property change, foreign key relationship gets lost

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map my updated model to the entity. The issue I am facing is that when I change a property of student object, for example: `IsPressent`, after the update method then `Driver` reference becomes null. I think I am doing something wrong with the update method. I appreciate any help or hint.

Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsPressent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional
    /// </summary>
    public int? DriverRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DriverRefId")]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

Driver class:

```
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public bool IsPressent { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper profile:

```
public class StudentProfile : Profile
{
    public StudentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Student, Student>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.DriverRefId, opt =>
            {
                // If driver is not null
                opt.Condition(x => x.Driver != null);

                opt.MapFrom(x => x.Driver.Id);
            });
    }
}
```

Update method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates entity given the id and instance
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <param name="updatedInstance"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public virtual T Update(int id, T updatedInstance)
{   
    var instance = GetDbSet().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if (instance != null)
    {
        instance = GetMapper().Map(updatedInstance, instance);
        GetDbSet().Update(instance);
        GetDbContext().SaveChanges();
        return updatedInstance;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to manually map instance to the entity type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to eager load the driver reference using the *Include* keyword:

```
 var instance = GetDbSet().Include(s.Driver).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: you should make sure to do it for the updated instance as well

Comment: you might also have to explicitly map the driver reference instead of only mapping the id